# Links/Clicks not working in Firefox after Using the Back button on an XPage

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, xpages

I'm finding that XPages I have, when loaded in Firefox, have an odd quirk that I can't seem to get around. On my XPage, there is a viewPanel, in which one of the columns is defined as such:

```
<xp:viewColumn styleClass="viewAction" id="View">
 <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
 <xp:viewColumnHeader value="View" id="viewColumnHeader2">
 </xp:viewColumnHeader>
 <xp:image url="/imgs/viewBtn.png" id="image2" styleClass="linkImg">
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
   <xp:this.action>
    <xp:openPage name="/Inspection.xsp" target="openDocument" documentId="#javascript:InspectionDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID();}">
    </xp:openPage>
   </xp:this.action>
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:image>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

When I click this link and go to the next page, it loads fine. If I use the Back button in Firefox ONLY, however, and try to click in this link again, nothing happens. It takes about 10-15 seconds for the link to do anything once clicked, and no action is queued until that time. The same goes for other elements on the page, including Links with click events, and a combo box with an on change event, but strangely enough, my dojo dropdown menus work immediately.

Hoping someone else has seen this, or has an idea I can give a shot!

Thanks
Aaron Brake
4CTechnologies

Comment: I thought this was just me. I find that buttons and partial refreshes simply stop working in Firefox after reloading the page a few times. Have to clear the cache, close and restart FF to get it to work again.  I have also tried removing all add-ons and extensions with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The XSP object has this property called submitLatency, it has a default setting of 20 seconds.  This is probably your problem.  The goal of it is to keep your end users from submitting the form twice and running your business logic twice.  You can change the submitLatency field by using:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
XSP.submitLatency = 1000;
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm... I can give that a shot. Does that mean that Firefox thinks that navigating to a page through a back event is a form submission? That seems weird...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set HTTP Header *Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store*?