# Caching / redirect issues in Firefox?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a custom control that is placed on selected pages of my site.  The control's before page load event calls java code that checks to see if the users password is expired in eDirectory.   If the password is expired, the custom control redriects the user to the password change screen where the user can change their password.  Using a scope variable, the actual check runs only once per session.

All works great in IE.  In FireFox the expired password is detected correctly and the password change screen is displyed correctly.  But if a user tries to go back to the page that triggered the password change then they are taken to the password change screen instead.

It seems to be the browswer that is directing them to the password change screen because when the java code runs, I print lots of diagnostic messages to the log.    I am only seeing the intial check of the password in the log no matter how many times I try to go to requested page.  In theroy I should see multiple enteries in the log for every time I am taken to the page.

As long as a page has never triggered a password change then I can go to that page with no problems.  But if it does trigger a change then I can no longer go to that page as it will take me to the password change screen.

If I clear the cache in FirFox then all works great up until the next password change.

What makes this issue more frustrating is that it only appears to occur on our reverese proxy server.  We have an apacahe reverse proxy to allow outside our firwall browsers to get to our site.  The reverse proxy server connects to a load balanncer server and that to one of two Domonio servers.

Any idea how I would fix this very strange caching issue?

Here is the code that runs in the Before Page Load event.

```
var pwdExpired:boolean = sessionScope.get("pwdExpired");

if (pwdExpired == null)
 {
var ldap:com.pnc.cld.LDAPauthentication = new com.pnc.cld.LDAPauthentication();
if (ldap.isPasswordExpired(@Name("[CN]",@UserName())))
{
    sessionScope.put("pwdExpired",true);
    var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    extCont.redirect(getURI("xp_pgChangePwd.xsp"));


}
else
    sessionScope.put("pwdExpired",false);

}
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of weird issues in firefox. I had a question earlier about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610593/links-clicks-not-working-in-firefox-after-using-the-back-button-on-an-xpage, maybe it's something with the cache there as well, keeping the timeout variables even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Do you set sessionScope variable to null when user changes password? Seem to be logical bug to me. Consider changing the variable to viewScope.

Comment: What http Header / Meta tags are you are adding to your XPages?

Comment: Have you tried to set HTTP Header *Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store*?

Comment: @Arron -I set the sessionScope to true or false depending if pw is expired or not.  I also set it to false if there is a successful update.  I only go to ldap if pwdExpired  is null.  I can't use a viewScope varibale.  That would not make any sense.  I might as well not use one at all then.

Comment: @Sven - So far your response seems to be the answer.  I am having our admins move the changes to QA where I will need to test to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sven's suggestion at least seems to have fixed this issue.  The issue is reported to also occur in IE9.  I am not certain this solution fixes that or not as I have not been able to test it yet.

Here is how I fixed the issue:

```
var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response = extCont.getResponse();

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
```